# Percentage symbol in TextView with one decimal point

Tags: android, textview, symbols

How can I set the percentage symbol to a TextView  with one decimal point in Android?
 I have tried using the unicode symbol but its not working.

```
textES.setText(String.format("%.1f \u0025",percentage));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this.

```
textES.setText(String.format("%.1f",percentage) + "%");
```